# URL hash format, what's allowed and what's not?

Tags: html, url, browser

I'm using hash-based navigation in my rich web app. I also found I needed to create permalinks that would point to single instances of resources, but since I cannot cause the page o refresh, and the main page is loaded from a single path '/', I cannot use *real* URLs. Instead I thought about using hashes. Let me give you an example because I know the explanation above sucks.

So, instead of having http://example.com/path/to/resource/1, I would have http://example.com/#path/to/resource/1

This seems to work ok, and browser believes '#path/to/resource/1' is a hash (slashes permitted, I think) but I was wondering about what characters are allowed in URL hash. Is there a specification or a RFC that I could read to find out what the standard behavior of browsers is when it comes to hashes?

**EDIT:** Ok, so silly me. Didn't actually check if slashes worked in all browsers. Chrome obviously doesn't like them. Only works in FF.

Comment: `Didn't actually check if slashes worked in all browsers. Chrome obviously doesn't like them. Only works in FF.` - Hmm, I've had no problem in Chrome or any browser for that matter.

Comment: @Wesley: Dunno, I started using them becuse FF 3.6 agreed it was a good idea. And then I tested in Chrome which behaved differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at: http://www.w3.org/Addressing/rfc1630.txt or http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_2_Fragments.html

Basically you can use anything that can be encoded in an URL.

Note: There might be browser inconsistencies. If you fear them, you might use a serialization mechanism, like converting the string to hex or something (will be twice longer though), or use an id of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

[This document](http://labs.apache.org/webarch/uri/rfc/rfc3986.html#rfc.section.3.5) should help. Slashes are allowed, but the lexical analysis might differ between browsers.

Comment: Yeah, Chrome definitely doesn't think slashes are part of the hash, so I reverted to dashes. Thanks for the link, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find that useful: [RFC3986](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html)

If you use PHP to generate your page paths you could also [urlencode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) which generates you a valide URL.

Comment: I do everything in JavaScript. That's why I need hashes instead of regular URLs.